# How to use google-cast for Android and iOS together with Cordova for a mobile webapp?

Tags: cordova, google-cast, chromecast

We have an Android-App and an iOS-App, both are not native apps, they are build with Apache Cordova.
In the documentation for the Chromecast Sender Apps, I see that the lifecycle in the Google Cast SDK for Android and for iOS is different. Now we are wondering, if it is possible to use a Cordova-Plugin that will work for Android and for iOS.

Do you have some experience, how to integrate the Chromecast-API with Cordova. Do you know plugins, that we could use? 
Or would you generally recommend to use the Chromecast APIs only in native apps? Do you see any technical problems to integrate the chromecast functionality in an app, that is build with Cordova, that only displays the mobile webpage?

In worst case I see three different "applications" that we have to implement. One for Android, one or iOS and one for the desktop. The third one, only  if we want to support the chrome-browser with its chromcast-plugin, too. Do you agree with that?

Answer (score 1):

I haven't worked with Cordova much, but my limited understanding is that they have a native shell/container. Before I get into details, I would say that using native clients makes your life much easier. With that said, what you can potentially do is the following:

- Add Cast capabilities through the native shell.
- Manage the cast related states in that native container
- Write a good amount of code in both the native shell and the javascript side of your app to provide bi-directional communication bridge (apis) between these two pieces. For example the native shell starts discovery of devices and as it finds devices, it keeps a list of them and a the same time informs (using the abovementioned bridge/apis) the web component that a new device was discovered and the web component populates its own list so that when user clicks on an appropriate button in the web component, it shows a list. Similarly, when user selects an item, the web component should call an api on the native part to tell t that a route is selected, etc.

As you can see, you need to duplicate a lot of logic and keep the two worlds in sync. Is it doable? I believe so, but it is a costly activity. The implementation of native part is clearly platform dependent.

Comment: can you clarify a little further? I seem to be confused. Is it correct that you advocate for a native app, neglecting Cordova and may opt for a Restful webservice as backend instead of a HTML-page used by the cordova-browser? In that case, the doublication of logic comes per supported platform (via the native app).

Comment: I am simply saying that the native platforms (Android and iOS) are the only ones that support Cast apis at this point. So for a web page inside Cordova to handle cast, it has to communicate with the native platform, and that makes that portions platform dependent.

Comment: In theory, somebody could write a Cast Cordova plugin. That plugin would be native and connect to the native platform Cast SDK. The API exposed to the Cordova app by the plugin could be cross-platform, barring irreconcilable differences in the Android and iOS APIs of the Cast SDK.

Comment: you are wrong there is javascript version of sender as well.

Comment: Correct. The JavaScript API requires an installed Chrome extension on the desktop Chrome browser, so it doesn't really help much. Though it could act as a nice blueprint for a the Cordova plug-in's API.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of solutions that bridge the gap between Cordova/Phonegap and Cast native functionality, providing a JavaScript API layer over the native libraries. [Here's one example](https://github.com/AVGP/cordova-chromecast). You'll either need to use a plug-in like this (if you can get it to work -- there's pretty much no documentation) or write your own plug-ins using Java and Objective-C that essentially relay Chromecast functionality to Cordova.